# How to find declaration of a variable using Clang?

Tags: c++, clang

I'm trying to analyse some c++ code using Clang. For the following code, I'm able to retrieve `Expr* x` as an argument of `f-> bar(x)` from AST. Now, I want to find the declaration of `x` in order to get its initial value but I'm not sure how I could do this. I also looked into the `Expr` documentation in here http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Expr.html but I couldn't find anything useful.

```
struct foo {
  int bar(int x) { return x; }
};

int main(){
  foo *f;
  int x = 0, y = 0;
  int y = f->bar(x); 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html?

Comment: No, I haven't. Actually I'm writing a checker for Clang, this one is for building a new tool for Clang! But anyway, thanks. I might use it!

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
dynamic_cast<const VarDecl*>(dynamic_cast<const DeclRefExpr*>(x)->getDecl())->getInit();
```

Comment: I've just tried this now, the compiler complains " error: dynamic_cast from 'const clang::Expr *' to 'clang::DeclRefExpr *' casts away qualifiers". I think It's because DeclRefExpr * is not constant!